# How do we apply conditional formatting based on cell to the left and above but also account for blanks present in between

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I am comparing a range of cells and need their values to be aligned lowest - Highest not just when looking from left to right but also from top to bottom. I have used conditional formatting to compare value to its left and highlight it in yellow and compare above and highlight in red.

This method works fine but since my data has blank cells (which must remain as is) it is not fully accurate since it only compares to the blank cell beside it but not the cell which has a value one or two more cells further to the left.

As you can see in the image, M7<J7 but it does not get highlighted since M7 is being compared to L7 which is blank

[image]
Is there a formula I can use which skips the blank cells and only compares the cells which have a value.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 1):

You can use formulas for conditional formatting like on the screenshot below.
Formulas always refer to the first cell of the formatted area.
Number `10^6` is a number which is greater than any number in your data.
Use not mutually exclusive ways of formatting e.g. fill colour and fill pattern for rows and columns.
[image: Cond_Format]

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you apply the conditional formatting to all cells at once and not to separate sections of your number cluster
2. After the conditional formatting has been applied, click on "Conditional Formatting" and then "Manage Rules"

[image]

3. Select your formatting rule and then click on "Edit Rule"

[image]

4. Open the dropdown where it says "Minimum" and select "Number"

[image]

5. Enter the lowest value that you have in your sheet and click on "OK"
   [image]